# Remove Last 2 Words from comma delimited string

Tags: php, string

I have a string which is basically an address but can be various lengths. I need to remove the last 2 words from this string regardless of the length, the string is using commas to separate the words.

**Example**

Business Name, Street, Town, City, Region, Postcode

**Required Output**

Business Name, Street, Town, City

Thank you

Comment: So explode and array_splice can be used. Did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array_splice:

```php
$input = explode(',','Business Name, Street, Town, City, Region, Postcode');
$sliced = array_splice($input, -2);
```